# MySQL complex WHEN filter with CASE

Tags: mysql, case, case-when

I'm trying to figure out how to filter my output for a "combination" case. My first two statements work well and get me the lessons I want (i.e., snowboard lessons at the skier's ability level + unrated private lessons). My third statement (inPreferredLessonType = 3, that is, either snowboard or ski) fails to filter the output set properly--I will get any snowboard lessons or ski lessons whose various ability levels match EITHER of the skier's two (separately stored) ability levels. Not the right idea, and confusing to the user.

What I'd like is to get just the snowboard lessons at the skier's snowboard ability level + the ski lessons at the skier's ski ability level + unrated private lessons. Please help!

(...rest of SELECT statement...)

```
CASE 
WHEN inPreferredLessonType = 1 
  THEN program.nBool_isSnowboard = 0 AND 
(program.n_ability_level = inSkiAbilityLevel OR program.n_ability_level = 0)

  WHEN inPreferredLessonType = 2
  THEN program.nBool_isSnowboard = 1 AND 
(program.n_ability_level = inSnowboardAbilityLevel OR program.n_ability_level = 0)

  WHEN inPreferredLessonType = 3
  THEN program.n_ability_level = inSkiAbilityLevel 
       OR program.n_ability_level = inSnowboardAbilityLevel
       OR program.n_ability_level = 0   
END
```

(...rest of filter statements, ORDER BY, etc.)

Comment: is it the condition check inside `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yes, quite complex WHERE clause, I didn't include it here because I've debugged the rest.

Comment: `WHEN inPreferredLessonType = 3
   THEN (program.nBool_isSnowboard = 0 AND program.n_ability_level = inSkiAbilityLevel) 
   OR 
     (program.nBool_isSnowboard = 1 AND program.n_ability_level = inSnowboardAbilityLevel)
   OR 
   program.n_ability_level = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to bracket the conditions and filter to the ski vs. snowboard ability levels.

```
WHEN inPreferredLessonType = 3
      THEN (program.nBool_isSnowboard = 0 AND program.n_ability_level = inSkiAbilityLevel) 
            OR 
           (program.nBool_isSnowboard = 1 AND program.n_ability_level = inSnowboardAbilityLevel)
            OR 
            program.n_ability_level = 0
```